# Can a function increment the value of an int in the main function by incrementing it within the function (without using pointers)

Tags: c, function, integer, increment

The following code outputs `3`, but shouldn't the output be `2`, since I'm not using pointers interestingly, if I completely remove the array `a` from everywhere in the code, it outputs `2`.
Is this some property or a compiler malfunction?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void hi(int a[], int n) {
    a[n] = 3;
    n++;
    return;
}

int main() {
    int n = 2, i;
    int a[2] = { 1, 2 };
    hi(a, n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"since im not using pointers"*. But you are: the function argument `int a[]` isn't an array but decays to a pointer.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour.  `a[n] = 3;` in function `hi` with `n` == 2 is an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: I tested it. The above code output "2".

Comment: @Varnit Shukla Welcome to the StackOverFlow. Please vist [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Providing accurate information makes us easily to help you.   Please update the question as the code does not according to your description.

Comment: @XinCheng *your* compilation output `2` but the code has undefined behaviour. It can output any value, or crash.

Comment: Because you overwrite the boundary. Please provide an accurate example so that we can address the issue.

Comment: The main issue is about `a[n] = 3;`, Your array `a` only has size of 2. However `n` is 2.,  `a[2] =3` means you overwrite the 3rd element of the array with the value 3. Which is wrong. That's why the program would complains about that and abort running.  And for many compilers, variable `n` would be in memory adjacent to array `a`. that means `a[2]` is luckily points  to the address of `n`.  This is not an allowed behavior.

Comment: @XinCheng: Re “This is not an allowed behavior”: It is allowed. The C standard has no jurisdiction over what programmers may or may not do. It only specifies the interpretation of C programs and related rules. For this program, it does not define the behavior. And it does not prohibit anybody from writing, compiling, and executing the program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the reminder. I did not specify it clearly.  Yes, the C standard itself actually allows it. But you will get the error most of the time because most modern OSs do not allow that. Sorry, I did not specify it clearly early.  And if you use some very simple, prototype and old OSs, or customized compiler options, you can still do that without error. However It is just not supported by default in our default environment.

Answer (score 0):

Array a has 2 elements : a[0] and a[1].

Function hi() receives a pointer to a, so it will change array a[] in the main().

Now, the local variables in main() are using consecutive memory location:
a[0], a[1], n, i

When you change a[2] in hi() you change what is just after a[1], so you change n in this case.

If you swap declarations of n and i you will change i instead.

This is by design of the compiler. Other compilers may order local variables otherwise. Also the C language does not check out-of-bound indices of passed-in arrays.

Comment: Your guess seems correct, but you must be more explicit in your answer about **undefined behavior**: the behavior is undefined, anything could happen, nothing can be expected, variables may or may not use memory... it is not a *compiler malfunction*, it is a programmer error.